# Configuring an Access report to use a SQL Server stored procedure as its record source

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a report in MS Access 2010 with results of MS SQL Server Stored Procedure. In my VBA code I try:

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = CurrentDb.TableDefs("[MyTable]").Connect
qdf.SQL = "exec spMyProc @ID = " & "1"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True

Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

But it throws an error:

Run-time error '32585'
This feature is only availabe in an ADP.

What I'm doing wrong or how to fix that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a saved pass-through query in Access that executes your stored procedure. In this example I'll call the named query [myPassThroughQuery].

Edit your report to make `myPassThroughQuery` the `Record Source` for the report.

Now you can tweak the SP call before opening the report:

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("myPassThroughQuery")
qdf.SQL = "EXEC spMyProc @ID = " & "1"
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenReport "mySpReport", acViewPreview
```

Comment: "Create a saved pass-through query in Access that executes your stored procedure" - could you please write an example ? is query should be like exec spMyProc @Id = ???

Comment: @ihorko You could do it in VBA using the first five lines of code in your question, except use `.CreateQueryDef("myPassThroughQuery")` instead of `.CreateQueryDef("")`. Or you could use the Access GUI (`Create > Queries`).